# Вызвать запуск батника после завершения работы предыдущего Java

Tags: java

Есть таблица, в каждой строчке которой указан путь. Требуется пробежать по каждой строчке, взять путь и отправить в батник, но каждую последующую обрабатывать только после завершения работы батника с предыдущей строкой.
**data** это массив строк таблицы. **param1** и **param2** это параметры отправляемые в батник, третьим параметром отправляю строчку, с которой батник должен работать.

```
    for (int i=0; i < data.size(); i++) {
       ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
       pb.command("cmd", "/c", "start", "C:\file.bat", "param1,param2," + data.get(i);
        try {
         Process process = pb.start();  
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

В таком виде работает не плохо, но запускает столько исполнений Батника одновременно, сколько строк в таблице, не дожидаясь завершения работы с первой, второй и т.д. строкой. Как сделать, чтобы запуск работы со второй строкой, начался только после завершения работы с первой и т.д.?

Comment: [`process.waitFor();`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()) ?

Comment: @tym32167 действительно, практически идеально, но батники мелкие поэтому все-таки вылетают достаточно быстро друг за другом, забивая экран. Придется либо скрывать отображение cmd либо поставить Thread.sleep(2000), вроде поинтереснее уже смотрится. Может и на этот случай хитрость есть?

Comment: В общем на практике waitFor() не помог, т.к. он рапортует о завершении процесса с кодом 0, а по факту батник все еще работает со своими командами, cmd и процесс в диспетчере еще висит